# Class cast exception while loading image from webbu

Tags: android, image

Hello All I am trying to load image from web but I am getting Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$LimitedInputStreamm
```

My code for loading image is

```
private Drawable loadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
  {
              Log.i("WHERE","MenuPage loadImageFromWebOperations()");
          try
               {
                       InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                       Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                       return d;
               }
          catch (Exception e) 
               {
                       System.out.println("loadImageFromWebOperations ="+e);
                        Log.v("EXCEPTION AT ","FriendActivity loadImageFromWebOperations()");
                       return null;
               }
       }
```

Plz Help Me
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

use this method to download image.

```
  HttpGet httpRequest = null;
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity); 
            InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
            bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i am still not getting the loaded image in my imgeview , while i am printing in logcat, the image url is giving null from server.and the image is not loaded.